# How do i fix "Run-time error '1004'" when setting validation on a UserInterfaceOnly protected sheet with VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I am getting a "Run-time error '1004': Aplication-defined or object-defined error" when I try to set the validation on a cell using VBA. The sheet is protected using the UserInterFaceOnly flag set to true.

I tried moving the specific functions/subs to a blank workbook to see if the error repeated itself, and also without protection to see if it would still work. The problem was the same, and the code works if the sheet isn't protected. I googled the problem and found the link below suggests there's a character limit on the validation string but even restricting it to 200 chars didn't solve the problem.
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/what-is-limit-of-the-number-of-entries-in-excel/9ce4a909-8b03-428f-94a4-1b13433aa399

```vb
'pasting this code into a blank workbook, running ps and then running test should reproduce the problem
'set specific protection with pw
Sub ps()
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Unprotect Password:="secret"
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Protect Password:="secret", UserInterFaceOnly:=True
End Sub

'general protection sub
Public Sub protectSht(ws As Worksheet, pass As String)
    ws.Protect Password:=pass, UserInterFaceOnly:=True
End Sub

'set validation on cells
Sub setValidation(rng As Range, lst As Collection)
    Dim tmpstr As String
    Dim loopVar As Variant

    For Each loopVar In lst
            tmpstr = Trim(loopVar) & ", " & tmpstr
    Next loopVar

    If lst.Count = 0 Then
        rng.Validation.Delete
    Else
        With rng.Validation
        .Delete
        .Add xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
             Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=tmpstr
        End With
    End If
End Sub

'test function reproducing error
'run this on a sheet that's protected using ps
Sub test()
    Dim tst As New Collection
    tst.Add "hello"
    tst.Add "bye"
    tst.Add "etc"
    setValidation ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("B1:B5"), tst
End Sub
```

This should set the validation on the cells but regardless of whether they're locked or not it fails to do so. instead, it gives "Run-time error '1004': Aplication-defined or object-defined error" .

Comment: I suspect you need to add `DrawingObjects:=True` when protecting, as you're effectively adding/deleting a dropdown.

Comment: On which line does error occur?

Comment: Even though your protection is set to `UserInterFaceOnly:=True`, you'll still have to disable protection, add your validation, then re-protect.

Comment: @AntiDrondert The error occurs on the `.Add xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
             Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=tmpstr` line.

Comment: @PeterT I'm thinking that this is the only way at the moment but I'm not keen on using this as the user might change the workbook password which would break the script.

Comment: @PeterT In this case it would throw an Automation Error

Comment: If the workbook is managed by your own macros, then the users may have little need to change the password. Alternatively, you could store the password on a hidden worksheet instead of hard-coding it in your VBA. Then, perform a quick check to see if the user changed the password. If they have, display your own prompt to (re-)enter the new password so you can overwrite the password on the hidden worksheet. Setting it up this way ensures your code will always be runnable.

Comment: You haven't mentioned which version of Excel you're using - but..  as Excel has 'matured' over the years - the amount of things that you can get away with using `UserInterfaceOnly` has reduced. There was a time when you could set this without removing protection first for instance. Later, you could solve your problem with `DrawingObjects` option - but on the later versions the only option is to remove protection, apply validation and then reapply protection.

Comment: @CLR: In the end I went with the option of unprotecting the sheet, setting the validation, then reprotecting it.